# RabbitMQ - Handle multiple tasks simultaneously

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, task

I have N workers that consume my RabbitMQ tasks. But I want them to be able to consume multiple tasks simultaneously.

I read about the `prefetch_count` parameter which can allow me to do this, but it does not work.

Here is my code in Python, using Pika library:

```
import pika
import time

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % (body,))
    time.sleep(body.count(b'.'))
    print(" [x] Done")
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=2) # Here I should be able to handle 2 tasks in the same time
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='task_queue')

channel.start_consuming()
```

Unfortunately, if there is a task currently treated (so, basic_ack didn't send yet), the callback is not called for the second task. It waits the current task finished to start the next one.

Comment: how did you run N workers. i have same requirements where i want to run 10 workers. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is running synchronously, on a single thread.

set the prefetch to 1 and then create 2 instances of the consumer process on your computer. that will run both workers in parallel.

alternatively, you can do multi-threading... but i don't like multithreading, personally. i find it easier to manage more instances of a process, than to manage threads.

the example in [the RMQ tutorials for python](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) show this as a way to get parallel processing from multiple consumers